# Why does python recognise my object even when I haven't defined it?

Tags: python

Good day!

May I have somebody's help on a sample in a book that I am reading and trying to learn Python?

For the codes shown below. I’ve never define “each_score” so why this “each_score” is recognized by Python and running fine?

```
scores={}
result_f=open("py score.txt")
for line in result_f:
    (name,score)=line.split()
    scores[score]=name
result_f.close()

print("The top scores were:")
for each_score in scores.keys():
    print('surfer '+scores[each_score]+' scored '+each_score)
```

by the way, the text file content is simple as below:

```
Johnny 8.65
Juan 9.12
Joseph 8.45
Stacey 7.81
Aideen 8.05
Zack 7.21
Aaron 8.31
```

Comment: wow wow, thanks for the replies so soon!

Comment: Could I ask what book this came from?

Comment: I hope two surfers don't get the exact same score.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note - not an answer, but just a large comment that won't format in a comment field... Just some tips on learning (which I've had to write quickly as my battery is about to die...)

You should be looking to using the `with` where ever you need automatic resource closing (have a look at the fine manual)... Comprehensions can be useful (see the `dict` bit below)... 'Proper' naming of variables is also good - in this case `surfer_scores`... Unpacking tuples such as `for surfer, score` also adds readability, and using string formatting instead of concat'ing is also useful.

So after you've done the necessary learning bits, your above code could become something like:

```
with open('py score.txt') as fin:
    surfer_scores = dict(line.split() for line in fin)

for surfer, score in surfer_scores.iteritems():
    print('Surfer {} scored {} points'.format(surfer, score))
```

Answer (score 5):

No, you have defined it in your [`for` loop](http://wiki.python.org/moin/ForLoop).

In your example your variable should get the first value from your keys, on the second iteration the second value and so on.

Answer (score 2):

You are defining it in the loop. Every iteration `each_score` will get the current value of `score.keys()`.